# Aruco Detection: operating the inverse of the Pose results in strange value for Translation

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, inverse, marker, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i'm currently detecting the ArUco Marker with the help of the ros_aruco package. The detection works perfectly, i assume. by doing:
`$ rostopic echo /aruco_single/pose`
we obtain

```
header: 
  seq: 14
  stamp: 
    secs: 1548768525
    nsecs:  49234896
  frame_id: "camera"
pose: 
  position: 
    x: -0.0381913892925
    y: -0.0619406141341
    z: 0.542845368385
  orientation: 
    x: -0.550447938313
    y: 0.445001542715
    z: -0.464275720555
    w: 0.532380267752
```

By looking to the Z-Axis we can confirm that it's reading correctly, and the x and y as well (the marker is almost on the center of the camera). But this is the result of the transformation `marker -> camera`. What i really want is the transformation `camera -> marker`. Meaning we would had to do the inverse of this.

The way i do it:
Inverse of a Pose is given by: the inverse of a homogeneous transformation. Which eventually is just operating:

1. Inverse of the rotation = R.T; where T is the transpose and R the Rotation Matrix
2. Inverse of the position = -Rt * t; where Rt is the transpose of the Rotation matrix and t is the translation vector

What i get:

```
Tvec Inverted:
[[-0.43304875]
 [ 0.33646972]
 [-0.02163316]]
```

Which doesn't make sense because Z should maintain to be around 0.54. Does anybody know why the result is looking so strange?
Here is the snippet of the code:

```
def invert_pose(self, ps):
        # Storing the received pose
        x = ps.pose.position.x
        y = ps.pose.position.y
        z = ps.pose.position.z
        xyz = x, y, z
        tvec = np.array(xyz)
        print ("Tvec: ")
        print tvec

        rx = ps.pose.orientation.x
        ry = ps.pose.orientation.y
        rz = ps.pose.orientation.z
        rw = ps.pose.orientation.w
        quaternion = [rx, ry, rz, rw]
        eule_ang = euler_from_quaternion(quaternion)
        rvec = np.array(eule_ang)
        R = np.matrix(cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)[0])
        Rt = R.T
        invR = self.rotation_matrix_to_euler_angles(Rt)
        invT = -Rt.dot(np.matrix(tvec).T)
    

        print "Tvec Inverted: "
        print invT
        self.publish_ros(invR, invT)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314121/aruco-detection:-operating-the-inverse-of-the-pose-results-in-strange-value-for-translation/) by [hpoleselo](https://answers.ros.org/users/37369/hpoleselo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2019-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-01-29**:
Why should Z still be around 0.54? There is a fairly significant rotational element of the pose so I would expect the z translation to be shifted too. More generally, don't reinvent the wheel, the TF package has the inverse operation built in and tested.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-29**:\

> More generally, don't reinvent the wheel, the TF package has the inverse operation built in and tested.

indeed. I was going to comment on this as well.

@hpoleselo: any reason you don't / cannot use [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2)?

**Comment by [hpoleselo](https://answers.ros.org/users/37369/hpoleselo/) on 2019-01-30**:
Hi, thank you both for the quick response. I actually didn't know about this function from /tf package. Conclusion: I thought for some reason i had to publish the Pose on the camera frame_id and then invert it, but actually what i had to do was to create a broadcaster between the camera and marker->

**Comment by [hpoleselo](https://answers.ros.org/users/37369/hpoleselo/) on 2019-01-30**:
->  then ROS identified automatically that in order to the relation marker->camera to be valid, it should be inverted to fit the tf_tree (Because the camera is attached to a robot on RVIZ). Bottom line, just create the broadcaster. I can post the code here if you guys think it would help others.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-01-30**:
Yes, publishing to the TF system is the way forward then ROS takes care of everything.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-30**:
I'm not sure I understand: if aruco is already publishing `marker -> camera` and you're interested in the inverse, why are you broadcasting your own transform? Wouldn't a simple `lookUp(..)` invert it for you automatically?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-01-30**:
Arcu ROS only publishes Pose messages, it doesn't broadcast the TFs itself.

**Comment by [hpoleselo](https://answers.ros.org/users/37369/hpoleselo/) on 2019-01-30**:
ROS never fails to surprise me, very nice! Thank you both for the help! About the lookUp(): exactly like Pete said!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-30**:\

> Arcu ROS only publishes Pose messages, it doesn't broadcast the TFs itself.

Right, I forgot about that. Depends on the pkg used though I believe.

Could probably be done using a(n almost) one-liner with [topic_tools/transform](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/transform).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @gvdhoorn and @PeteBlackerThe3rd answered on the comments, there was a built in function from `/tf` which is called inverse. But that wasn't needed since the `/tf` package itself recognizes the direction of the `tf_tree` (forward) and then inverse it (`camera -> marker`) for us.

---

Originally posted by [hpoleselo](https://answers.ros.org/users/37369/hpoleselo/) with karma: 133 on 2019-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1